Neural Network not learning sinusoidal function parameters
I have a sinusoidal function like below with pre defined a, b and c parameters
def fun_sin(a, b, c, apply_noise=False):
    """
    Returns a function representing a sinusoidal curve with noise.

    Parameters:
        a: Amplitude of the sine wave.
        b: Frequency of the sine wave.
        c: Phase shift of the sine wave.
    """
    def ann(x):
        x = torch.tensor(x, dtype=torch.float32).to(device) if not isinstance(x, torch.Tensor) else x.to(device)
        return (a * torch.sin(b * x + c)) + torch.tensor(random_gen.random(x.shape) * 0.2 if apply_noise else 0).to(device)
    return ann

fun, a, b, c, learning_rate = fun_sin, 4, 0.1, 2, 0.0001

Here's a sample of the curve of this function:

I created a neural net to, given X (points in the x axis) and Y values (result of fun_sin(a, b, c)(X)) I want my network to figure what where the a, b, c that generated that curve. In order to do that I make the output layer to spit out 3 values and create a function with those parameters like so
def loss_fun(label, pred):
  return torch.mean((label - pred) ** 2)

...

my_model =  nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(X_length, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, 32),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(32, 3)  # Output layer with 3 parameters (a, b, c)
        )
...

my_model.train()
for i in epochs:
  optimizer.zero_grad()
  pred_a, pred_b, pred_c = my_model(X)
  Y_pred = fun_sin(pred_a, pred_b, pred_c)(X)
  loss = loss_fun(Y_label, Y_pred)
  loss.backward()
  optimizer.step()

So here's the deal: my network learns quite reasonably if I give it up to about 100 data entries for X and Y; I'm able to find good predictions for a, b and c that are able to render a sinusoidal curve very much similar to my original one. However, if I pass more data, by increasing X & Y length (in batches or not), the network stops giving out good loss results.
I've tried multiple approaches to make this better:

normalizing the data
playing with various learning rates and different schedulers (LambdaLR, OneCycleLR)
creating less complex networks (less neurons, less layers)
creating more complex and deep networks
changing optimizers (Adam, SGD, etc.)
doing random restarts
doing gradient clippings
doing batch propagation of gradients vs doing single propagation per epoch
removing the noise I have in fun_sin
checked that the extra data I'm passing is all good (plotted graphs and checked mean/std too)
tried various different loss functions that would penalize the network more for mistakes

I just cant get a reasonable loss when I have more data. I've read this article https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.00425 that talks about why neural nets have issues with converging cyclic curves when their frequencies are high but in my case the parameter b which is what's driving the frequency is pretty low (0.1) so don't think that applies here (also, if I have less data the network learns well).
Does anyone know what issue I could be facing here?

ReLU-based architectures struggle with modeling global periodic functions with large amount of data because ReLU is inherently piecewise linear and non-periodic. Try to switch to Sine Activation Functions in at least the first layer. Also try normalize Inputs to a small range, e.g., [-1, 1] or [0, 2π].

I managed to find this paper that explores problems like the one I described above:
https://arxiv.org/pdf/2006.09661: "Implicit Neural Representations with Periodic Activation Functions"
The paper proposes a Sine activation based architecture (SIREN) that is better than ReLU based ones at modelling cyclic curves even on high frequencies.
It also encourages uniformed distribution weight initialization on locations where the derivative of sin(x), cos(x) is not 0 so as to avoid gradient vanishing. Using both approaches solved my problem.
Here's part of the relevant code:
class SineActivation(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, x):
        return torch.sin(x)

class SineLinearLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features):
        super(SineLinearLayer, self).__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features
        self.linear = nn.Linear(in_features, out_features)
        self.init_weights()

    def init_weights(self):
        with torch.no_grad():
            self.linear.weight.uniform_(-1 / self.in_features, 1 / self.in_features)

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.linear(x)


def create_sine_model(input_len):
    return nn.Sequential(
            SineLinearLayer(input_len, 128),
            SineActivation(),
            SineLinearLayer(128, 64),
            SineActivation(),
            SineLinearLayer(64, 3)  # Output layer with 3 parameters (a, b, c)
        )



Really you only need 1 sine function to model a your sine function, right?
